# how to use require_once?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

 require_once '../db/db.php';

   $id = $_GET ['id'];

   $display = $conn->QUERY("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE id = $id");

   if($display)
   {
          header('location: index.php');
    }

   ?>
```

- how to use '../'?
- I get error like this pic  but I refresh the page deleted data.
   
  [image]
- I stored db.php inside db folder
   
  [image]

Comment: '../' isnt a feature of `require_once`. [see the wiki entry on 'paths'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: And relative paths in PHP are relative to the invocation script or current working directory, not the script they're used in.

Comment: I just want to learn it.. what wrong with me?? you all want to dislike my post?

Comment: @ikramlim since your `index.php` and `db.php` are both in the same folder why do you even have to use `../` ?

Comment: is it like this https://i.gyazo.com/53c04ad7b8d89a233ede9439090bf372.png ?

Comment: I getting this result https://i.gyazo.com/08455071295aec78492784caa30eea46.png

Comment: @ikramlim No, what you're trying to do is to find a folder named `db` inside the already made folder named `db`. Please check my answer.

Comment: Hang on guys, the error posted is an **HTTP 404** - _not a fatal error regarding_ `require_once`. @ikramlim, are you sure you're navigating to the correct URL?

Comment: Thanks @HPierce resolved problem.

Comment: @ikramlim, I just posted it (and way more context) as an answer - you should consider reading it over. There was a lot of confusion thrown around here that I think it resolves.

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted a screenshot of is an [HTTP 404 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) - that means none of your PHP was ever executed because the web server couldn't find `index.php`. Put another way, the error you posted is totally unrelated to `require_once`, because `require_once` was never called.

When a require fails, you get this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required **[filename]**

However, based on your comments under @HawasKaPujaari's answer you resolved the 404 issue (either accidentally or intentionally). the include path should look like this:

```
<?php
//Source Files/index.php

//@HawasKaPujaari seems to think db is on the same level as index.php. I disagree. 
require_once "db/db.php";

// ...
?>
```

Please be aware, the code snippet above assumes that it is in `index.php`. As @mario says in the comments, PHP `require`/`include` paths are relevant to the executing script (in this case `index.php`), not the script it is located in. So calling a `require` from `Source Files/db/db.php` needs a path relevant to `Source Files/index.php` **not** `Source Files/db/db.php`.

Side note: I have no idea what @castis is talking about. using `../` seems to be perfectly valid in a `require` path. It's just that `db.php` isn't located there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `index.php` and `db.php` are both in the same folder, you don't have to use the `../` to go back.

Change this:

```
require_once '../db/db.php';
```

to this:

```
require_once ('db.php');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, OP doesn't confirm one way or the other that the script is being invoked from `index.php` (though it might be a fair assumption). Also, looks like `db.php` is located at `Source Files/db/db.php` and index.php is located at `Source Files/index.php`

Comment: this is the result: https://i.gyazo.com/a0966fa7affee2f5c384056aaa9a8132.png

Comment: @HPierce I can't do the path like that? i not understand about the path how to do it. I tried my style also get error.. but I tried this require_once '../db/db.php' error but result can get deleted.